# Join strings from the same column in ´pandas´ using a placeholder condition

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, function, dataframe, apply

I have a series of data that I need to filter. 
The df consists of one col. of information that is separated by a row with with value NaN.

I would like to join all of the rows that occur until each NaN in a new column.

For example my data looks something like:

```
the
car
is
red
NaN
the
house
is
big
NaN
the
room
is
small
```

My desired result is

```
B
the car is red
the house is big
the room is small
```

Thus far, I am approaching this problema by building a function and applying it to each row in my dataframe. See below for my working code example so far.

```
def joinNan(row):
    newRow = []
    placeholder = 'NaN'
    if row is not placeholder:
        newRow.append(row)
    if row == placeholder:
        return newRow


df['B'] = df.loc[0].apply(joinNan)
```

For some reason, the first row of my data is being used as the index or column title, hence why I am using 'loc[0]' here instead of a specific column name.

If there is a more straight forward way to approach this directly iterating in the column, I am open for that suggestion too.

For now, I am trying to reach my desired solution and have not found any other similiar case in Stack overflow or the web in general to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for test `NaN`s is necessary use [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html), then greate helper `Series` by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and aggregate `join` with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df=df.groupby(df[0].isna().cumsum())[0].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())).to_frame('B')
#for oldier version of pandas
df=df.groupby(df[0].isnull().cumsum())[0].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())).to_frame('B')
```

Another solution is filter out all `NaN`s before `groupby`:

```
mask = df[0].isna()
#mask = df[0].isnull()
df['g'] = mask.cumsum()

df = df[~mask].groupby('g')[0].apply(' '.join).to_frame('B')
```

Comment: works great except for issue that I have with the column names. Unless I specify the specific string where you indicate [0], it throws me a key error. The when I specify df.loc[0], I get the following attrtibute error. ´AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method´

Comment: so try use `df['0']`

Comment: I don't think that will work because the name of the column is not the string '0'. It is a string (alpha) that actually should be the first row of data in my dataframe. I would have thought that dff.loc[0] would solve this, but the key error continues

Comment: @owwoow14 - What return `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: it is the following : ['the']

Comment: So it is wrongly column name. Do you read data from csv? Then use `df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['col'])` and change my solution from `df[0]` to `df['col']`

Comment: i am reading the data in from a csv. However, there are other columns in the file and I use that information for another filter. Is it possible to access the column without the name (by index number). It will always be 0. Which is why i tried df.loc[0] to solve that.

Comment: `df.loc[0]` is not possible use here, because it select first index and you need select first column - need `df[0]`

Comment: yes, doing that works perfectly I will accept your answer. However, I do need the header information eventually. I can open another question for this issue.